# Checkbox appears out of bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap panel and inside of that, I have a form.

Inside the `form`, I have form elements such as a `checkbox`. See the example below.

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Panel</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="1234" name="fieldname" value="1234">
                <label for="1234">Text</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is the checkbox appears on or slightly before the panel left border. I can see the CSS of the checkbox is telling it to `position: absolute` and `margin-left: -20px`.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zs9kw0ec/2/

Is there a way to fix this rather than messing about with adding margins?

Answer (score 2):

I have used and it works fine:

> Here's the link to docs
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

```html
 <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
      </div>
```

**Here's the link to fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zs9kw0ec/4/

Answer (score 2):

`form.less` contain CSS styling which directly applied to the checkbox.

You need to overwrite this rule in your CSS file.

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-left: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.less` CSS contain in `row 237`:

```css
 .radio input[type="radio"],
 .radio-inline input[type="radio"],
 .checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
 .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: -20px;
     margin-top: 4px \9;
 }
```

Change `margin-left: -20px;` to `margin-left: 0px`